# How to manage a login form with ExtJS6 cookie provider and state.Manager + OL3 for webmapping application?

Tags: javascript, extjs, cookies, authentication, openlayers-3

I'm building a webmapping application that will have a login form to determine if a user is a simple user or an admin. Depending on the user type, the page loaded next will be different.

The admin page will consist of the full map application and the user page will consist of a simple map viewer application.

I want the admin to be able to save the map state configuration for a specific user (layers added, map center, zoom, etc.). When this user will connect to the website, it will load the specific configuration saved for him and load the viewer with it.

I know that I can save some map configuration into "keys" in the `Ext.state.Manager` configured with a cookieprovider, but that's all I really know how to do for the moment and my question is more "user access oriented".

So:

1) How do I store the usernames/password/usertype configuration for my login form ?

**Edit:** Ok i managed to do that with a Apache server and a PHP login script.

2) How do I store the saved configs for a spectific user ?

3) How do I retrieve a specific configuration for a determined user ?

Thanks for your ideas and tips !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great tutorial that explains step by step how to do that with ExtJS5, C# and MySQL.

[Check it out here.](http://jorgeramon.me/2015/creating-a-custom-ext-js-state-provider/)